# Nested fragment-No activity to handle intent

Tags: android, fragmenttransaction, android-nested-fragment, fragmentmanager

I have an activity with fragment A added to it dynamically. Now, I transact from fragment A to fragment B. And then from fragment B to fragment C. Now I have a button here when clicked will place a call. I'm not able to start the call intent and the error log says illegal state exception - No activity found to handle the intent. Does it mean that there's no activity found for the nested fragment C? How can this happen (fragment creation without activity)? Also all fragments are dynamically created during run time. 
I tried this using both getfragmentmanager() and getchildfragmentmanager() method. 
I face this error in both the cases. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Here's my code snippet

Attaching Fragment A to activity

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.container,FragmentA_.builder().build());
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Replacing Fragment A with Fragment B

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.container, FragmentB_.builder().build());
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Replacing Fragment B with Fragment C

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.container, FragmentC_.builder().build());
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Call intent

```
public void call(String contact){
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+contact));
getActivity().startActivity(i);
}
```

In my manifest.xml I have added all permissions for Call.

**Edit - 2**
Fragment C code

```
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_c)
public class FragmentC extends Fragment
{
@Click(R.id.call_button)
void call(){
call(phone_number);
}
  public void call(String contact){
    Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+contact));
    getActivity().startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: No , I am pretty sure that I've followed the order of attachment as mentioned in my question. Also I only added fragment A , rest all fragments I've used replace method.

Comment: can you post the code where you are initiating the call intent, also I wanna take a look at your permissions.

Comment: Could you please share some code ?

Comment: Code added bro .. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure `contact` is a valid number? Does `ACTION_DIAL` work?

Comment: Yes I checked and it works .. And yeah the number is a valid one

Comment: Could you include the code for `FragmentC` in your question please?

Comment: Added the code dude..

Comment: Remove getActivity(). Call directly startActivity(i);

Comment: You can't do that inside a fragment .. You either need a context holding activity reference or the activity itself

Comment: @Krishna, Have you tried it? You can startActivity from any fragment without hosting activity reference.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet for the same ?

Comment: @Krishna, Just remove getActivity() from your code and I think it should work!

Comment: No bro.. I tried.. It gives me method does not exist error

Comment: Fragment does have startActivity method. For more information: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: I see that ListFragment has that method but what about a normal fragment ?

Comment: Every fragment has that method. Kindly verify are you using the right imports

Comment: @YasirTahir  sorry man. I'll check that and re run the code again. I think there's a problem with my imports.

Comment: Any update? Working fine now?

Comment: I came to office back bro.. Shall I update you tonight ?? Thanks a bunch for timely response though !

Comment: @YasirTahir Bro... Thanks a ton man ! It worked !!! Can you change this comment to an answer and I'll accept it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove getActivity() and Call directly startActivity(i)

Fragments have its own startActivity() method. You don't need to pass activity context or reference in this case. For more information: [Click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the timely response mate ! Really appreciate it !